# C++ time_point на этой неделе

Tags: c++

Дана дата создания объекта в формате chrono time_point. Как по этой дате определить, что это дата "вчера", "на этой неделе", "в этом месяце" или "в этом году" на современном C++?

Мои попытки:

```
static inline bool in_this_week(time_point<system_clock> &time)
{
    const auto now = system_clock::to_time_t(system_clock::now());
    const auto current = *std::localtime(&now);
    
    return current.
}
```

не знаю, как реализовать.

Comment: Ну, в этом месяце и в этом году — просто: перегоняете через `localtime` в `struct tm` и сравниваете год с нынешним, или месяц с нынешним. Для недели — находите начало недели для сегодняшнего дня, и смотрите, попадает ли в интервал 7\*24 часа. Для вчера примерно так же, только отматываете на сутки и на начало суток. Но в целом как по мне, так проще написать свою библиотеку, чем разобраться с тем, что начудили в стандартной. Какая-то она интуитивно запутанная, мягко говоря...